# com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type Model(In Fragment)

Tags: java, android, firebase

My Problem

```js
01-04 18:05:36.912 2828-2828/com.p1519536gmail.recipies E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          Process: com.p1519536gmail.recipies, PID: 2828
                                                                          com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type Model.Ingredients
                                                                              at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdzr.zzb(Unknown Source:842)
                                                                              at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdzr.zza(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                              at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source:10)
                                                                              at com.firebase.ui.database.ClassSnapshotParser.parseSnapshot(ClassSnapshotParser.java:22)
                                                                              at com.firebase.ui.database.ObservableSnapshotArray.getObject(ObservableSnapshotArray.java:160)
                                                                              at com.firebase.ui.database.CachingObservableSnapshotArray.getObject(CachingObservableSnapshotArray.java:40)
                                                                              at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.getItem(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:180)
                                                                              at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:217)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6482)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6515)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5458)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5724)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5563)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5559)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2229)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1556)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1516)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:608)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3693)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3410)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.consumePendingUpdateOperations(RecyclerView.java:1710)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$1.run(RecyclerView.java:346)
                                                                              at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
                                                                              at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
                                                                              at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:655)
                                                                              at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

The user_id /cat_id

```js
//The user_id
final String cat_id = getRef(position).getKey();
                viewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Intent profileIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SingleRecipie.class);
                        profileIntent.putExtra("Category_id",cat_id);
                        startActivity(profileIntent);
                    }
                });
```

The Fragment XML file

```js
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="Fragment.recipie">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/cardView">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/recipie_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/recipie_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@color/overlayBackground"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Name of menu"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/ingredients_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cardView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The model for my Category, mRecipieDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Category")

```js
package Model;

/**
 * Created by Keiren on 1/4/2018.
 */

public class Category {
    private String Name;
    private String Image;

    //Constructor
    public Category() {
    }

    public Category(String Name, String Image) {
        this.Name = Name;
        this.Image = Image;
    }

    //Getter and Setter
    public String getName() {return Name;}

    public void setName(String Name) { this.Name = Name;}

    public String getImage() {
        return Image;
    }

    public void setImage(String Image) {this.Image = Image;
    }
}
```

Model for the Food , mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Food");

```js
package Model;

/**
 * Created by Keiren on 1/4/2018.
 */

public class Ingredients {
    private String x;



    public Ingredients() {

    }
    public Ingredients(String x) {
        this.x = x;
    }


    public String getX() {return x;}

    public void setX(String x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
}
```

I have no idea is it my DataSnapshot is conflicting with my Firebase Recycler View im still new at coding so im kinda lost as i have no idea where to look and its my first time coding using a fragment so its kinda confusing with the functions

```js
package Fragment;


import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.p1519536gmail.recipies.MainActivity;
import com.p1519536gmail.recipies.R;
import com.p1519536gmail.recipies.SingleRecipie;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import Model.Category;
import Model.Ingredients;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class recipie extends Fragment {

    private ImageView mImageView;
    private TextView mTextView;
    private View mMainView;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase,mRecipieDatabase;
    private RecyclerView Ingredients_list;


    public recipie() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mMainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recipie, container, false);
        mImageView = (ImageView) mMainView.findViewById(R.id.recipie_image);
        mTextView = (TextView)mMainView.findViewById(R.id.recipie_name);
        final String user_id = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("Category_id");
        mRecipieDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Category").child(user_id);
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Food");

        //Recycler View
        Ingredients_list = mMainView.findViewById(R.id.ingredients_list);
        Ingredients_list.setHasFixedSize(true);
        Ingredients_list.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));



        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return mMainView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        final Context c = getActivity().getApplicationContext();

        //View Name & Image
        mRecipieDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String name = dataSnapshot.child("Name").getValue().toString();
                String image = dataSnapshot.child("Image").getValue().toString();

                mTextView.setText(name);
                Picasso.with(c).load(image).into(mImageView);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });


        //Ingredients View Holder

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Ingredients, IngredientsViewHolder>firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Ingredients, IngredientsViewHolder>(
                Ingredients.class,
                R.layout.list_single_ingredients,
                IngredientsViewHolder.class,
                mDatabase

        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(IngredientsViewHolder viewHolder, Ingredients model, int position) {
                viewHolder.setX(model.getX());

            }
        };
        Ingredients_list.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

    }

    //ViewHolder
    public static class IngredientsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        View m2View;
        public IngredientsViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            m2View = itemView;
        }
        public void setX(String x){
            TextView IngredientsView = (TextView) m2View.findViewById(R.id.txt_ingredients);
            IngredientsView.setText(x);

        }

    }


}
```

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_ingredients"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/checkbox"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/checkbox"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/checkbox"
        android:text="Username Placeholder"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please edit this question to be more concise. This is far too much code and impossible to sift through. Include only the relevant code snippets, not everythign you've written . See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help writing your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47705534/databaseexception-cant-convert-object-of-type-java-lang-string-to-type)

Comment: Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You really need to troubleshoot this issue by stepping through your code to narrow down the problem area.

Answer (score 0):

I found my Answer

Instead of putting the Firebase Recycler into

```js
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState); 
}
```

put it inside

```js
@Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
```

thats the Solution, Separating 2 Retrieval of Database