# com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type models.firebase.FirebaseTripDataHolder

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get value of every node and its subnodes in the following heirarchy on firebase database. So, I had built the following object Model as a **First Approch**:

```
public class FirebaseTripDataHolder {
String currentStatus,distanceLengthStr, driverId, durationStr, fareEstimate ;

public FirebaseTripDataHolder() {
}

public FirebaseTripDataHolder(String key, String tripStatus, String distanceSTR, String driverIDStr, String durationStr, String fareEstimate) {
    currentStatus=tripStatus;
    distanceLengthStr=distanceSTR;
    driverId=driverIDStr;
    this.durationStr=durationStr;
    this.fareEstimate=fareEstimate;
}

public String getCurrentStatus() {
    return currentStatus;
}

public void setCurrentStatus(String currentStatus) {
    this.currentStatus = currentStatus;
}

public String getDistanceLengthStr() {
    return distanceLengthStr;
}

public void setDistanceLengthStr(String distanceLengthStr) {
    this.distanceLengthStr = distanceLengthStr;
}

public String getDriverId() {
    return driverId;
}

public void setDriverId(String driverId) {
    this.driverId = driverId;
}

public String getDurationStr() {
    return durationStr;
}

public void setDurationStr(String durationStr) {
    this.durationStr = durationStr;
}

public String getFareEstimate() {
    return fareEstimate;
}

public void setFareEstimate(String fareEstimate) {
    this.fareEstimate = fareEstimate;
}
}
```

Then, i made a for loop to get childrens of the DataSnapshot like the following snippet of code :

```
for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
     FirebaseTripDataHolder tripDataHolder= ds.getValue(FirebaseTripDataHolder.class);
     TripStatus= tripDataHolder.getCurrentStatus();
     DistanceSTR=tripDataHolder.getDistanceLengthStr();
     DriverIDStr=tripDataHolder.getDriverId();
     DurationStr=tripDataHolder.getDurationStr();
     FareEstimate=tripDataHolder.getFareEstimate();
}
```

However, the following line had returned an exception

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type models.firebase.FirebaseTripDataHolder

I tried to make some research on stackoverflow, and i reached too many solutions like **Alex Mamo's** answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47705534/databaseexception-cant-convert-object-of-type-java-lang-string-to-type?answertab=active#tab-top), it looked the same problem, i tried both of his solutions and used the **upcoming second Approach** too :

```
for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
     KEY = ds.getKey();
     TripStatus = ds.child("currentStatus").getValue(String.class);
     DistanceSTR = ds.child("distanceLengthStr").getValue(String.class);
     DriverIDStr = ds.child("driverId").getValue(String.class);
     DurationStr = ds.child("durationStr").getValue(String.class);
     FareEstimate = ds.child("fareEstimate").getValue(String.class);
}
```

But, in the second approach, dataSnapShot in OnDataChange method looked having data, but fileds are returning **null values** for each attribute. 
Also, i don't know how to complete my object to retrieve subnodes of my main DataSnapShot like : 
***customerCoordinates, customerInfo, distinationCoordinates *** in the following image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4N7Pj.png)

May anyone help in that problem. Thanks

**Update One(1)**
for more illustration, this is my json format coming from firebase in DataSnapShot key :

```
DataSnapshot { key = -Lv-5lEphq-F4TL1Q2_e, value = {distanceLength=12, customerCoordinates={address=Unnamed Road, lat=29.9774451, lng=31.2082394}, driverCoordinates={lat=29.977426, lng=31.212798}, fareEstimate=72, driverInfo={rate=5, name=driver29, deviceId=dYB0RihjjxY:APA91bFluyZ6iS0YDNKyY72TJl4Y9tx52MrVSwGKQkwJDuS9SVJ6XBlkpfCK1_bIIv675mY72cEr2en31qBPBzMOyaSE-zQHPBQJqdTDdkx-BZSyHZAeK5L1RBBrQRBuXPRsWiuJL2-h, mobile=01478529637}, durationStr=34 mins, distinationCoordinates={address=5 ش Ahmed Al Hasawi, lat=29.980184747972555, lng=31.25940430909395}, vehicleInfo={colorNames={ar=ازرق, en=Blue}, brandNames={ar=قيات, en=Fiat}, rideCategoryNames={ar=اقتصادي, en=Economy}, plateNo=789654, categoryNames={ar=تيبو, en=Tipo}, colorCode=#0000ff, typeNames={ar=موتوسكل, en=Bikes}}, currentStatus=Accept, customerInfo={name=mohamed, deviceId=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IkNVMTIxNjc4NzU2ODc3IiwiZW1haWwiOiJwcm9vZmVzc2VyQGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsInR5cGUiOiJDdXN0b21lciIsImlhdCI6MTU3NDEwMjE4MywiZXhwIjoxNTc2Njk0MTgzfQ.jqHNFmbLmOgS81y_vmpkVscsTDCrxBQiwfQPXuZLWTA, mobile=1097555350221}, driverId=DR472264941939, duration=34, distanceLengthStr=12.4 km} }
```

**update two(2)**
when datasnapshot looks like `DataSnapshot { key = currentStatus, value = Accept }` inside for loop like that :

```
for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    TripStatus = ds.child("currentStatus").getValue(String.class); 
}
```

TripStatus equals null

**Update Three(3)**

my firebase Database reference is :
tripsReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://wasalny-6139e.firebaseio.com/").getReference().child("trips").child(firebaseListenedTripID);

I am asking whether my Object is the suitable one, i needed to catch every node and subnode values in the **trips node** like i want to get the **customer coordinates, customer information, and destinationCoordinates**

**update Four (4)**
my firebaseDatabase json format instead of the attached image:

```
{
  "drivers" : {
    "DR117419391945" : {
      ".priority" : "stq6f8rfgx",
      "g" : "stq6f8rfgx",
      "l" : [ 30.0165321, 31.4097233 ]
    },
    "DR472264941939" : {
      ".priority" : "stq6fb27s5",
      "g" : "stq6fb27s5",
      "l" : [ 30.0166408, 31.4104284 ]
    }
  },
  "trips" : {
    "-Lv-BYEQPVDSV_AYAjPo" : {
      "currentStatus" : "Accept",
      "customerCoordinates" : {
        "address" : "Unnamed Road",
        "lat" : 29.9774637,
        "lng" : 31.2082546
      },
      "customerInfo" : {
        "deviceId" : "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IkNVMTIxNjc4NzU2ODc3IiwiZW1haWwiOiJwcm9vZmVzc2VyQGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsInR5cGUiOiJDdXN0b21lciIsImlhdCI6MTU3NDEwMjE4MywiZXhwIjoxNTc2Njk0MTgzfQ.jqHNFmbLmOgS81y_vmpkVscsTDCrxBQiwfQPXuZLWTA",
        "mobile" : "1097555350221",
        "name" : "mohamed"
      },
      "distanceLength" : 12,
      "distanceLengthStr" : "12.4 km",
      "distinationCoordinates" : {
        "address" : "5 ش Ahmed Al Hasawi",
        "lat" : 29.980184747972555,
        "lng" : 31.25940430909395
      },
      "driverCoordinates" : {
        "lat" : 29.977426,
        "lng" : 31.212798
      },
      "driverId" : "DR472264941939",
      "driverInfo" : {
        "deviceId" : "dYB0RihjjxY:APA91bFluyZ6iS0YDNKyY72TJl4Y9tx52MrVSwGKQkwJDuS9SVJ6XBlkpfCK1_bIIv675mY72cEr2en31qBPBzMOyaSE-zQHPBQJqdTDdkx-BZSyHZAeK5L1RBBrQRBuXPRsWiuJL2-h",
        "mobile" : "01478529637",
        "name" : "driver29",
        "rate" : 5
      },
      "duration" : 34,
      "durationStr" : "34 mins",
      "fareEstimate" : 72,
      "vehicleInfo" : {
        "brandNames" : {
          "ar" : "قيات",
          "en" : "Fiat"
        },
        "categoryNames" : {
          "ar" : "تيبو",
          "en" : "Tipo"
        },
        "colorCode" : "#0000ff",
        "colorNames" : {
          "ar" : "ازرق",
          "en" : "Blue"
        },
        "plateNo" : "789654",
        "rideCategoryNames" : {
          "ar" : "اقتصادي",
          "en" : "Economy"
        },
        "typeNames" : {
          "ar" : "موتوسكل",
          "en" : "Bikes"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Update Five (5)**
I had retreived all trips node and its subnodes in the dataSnapShot object, the problem is how to parse it to my FirebaseTripDataHolder object!?

Comment: Also add your `query` to `FirebaseDatabase`

Comment: i had added my query to FirebaseDatabase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't find your `query` to `FirebaseDatabase`. Try using below code:

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
database.getReference().child("trips").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            FirebaseTripDataHolder tripDataHolder = childSnapshot.getValue(FirebaseTripDataHolder.class);
            String TripStatus= tripDataHolder.getCurrentStatus();
            String DistanceSTR=tripDataHolder.getDistanceLengthStr();
            String DriverIDStr=tripDataHolder.getDriverId();
            String DurationStr=tripDataHolder.getDurationStr();
            long FareEstimate=tripDataHolder.getFareEstimate();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }

});
```

**FirebaseTripDataHolder.java**

```
public class FirebaseTripDataHolder {
    String currentStatus,distanceLengthStr, driverId, durationStr;
    long fareEstimate;

    public FirebaseTripDataHolder() {
    }

    public FirebaseTripDataHolder(String key, String tripStatus, String distanceSTR, String driverIDStr, String durationStr, long fareEstimate) {
        currentStatus=tripStatus;
        distanceLengthStr=distanceSTR;
        driverId=driverIDStr;
        this.durationStr=durationStr;
        this.fareEstimate=fareEstimate;
    }

    public String getCurrentStatus() {
        return currentStatus;
    }

    public void setCurrentStatus(String currentStatus) {
        this.currentStatus = currentStatus;
    }

    public String getDistanceLengthStr() {
        return distanceLengthStr;
    }

    public void setDistanceLengthStr(String distanceLengthStr) {
        this.distanceLengthStr = distanceLengthStr;
    }

    public String getDriverId() {
        return driverId;
    }

    public void setDriverId(String driverId) {
        this.driverId = driverId;
    }

    public String getDurationStr() {
        return durationStr;
    }

    public void setDurationStr(String durationStr) {
        this.durationStr = durationStr;
    }

    public long getFareEstimate() {
        return fareEstimate;
    }

    public void setFareEstimate(long fareEstimate) {
        this.fareEstimate = fareEstimate;
    }
}
```

Comment: so, what is the difference, i had posted the same and it is not successful till the moment!

Comment: You didn't post it. I have mentioned at first line that I didn't find your query. That's why I add the query and check it. Check your query in your code base which should be something like that `database.getReference().child("trips")`

Comment: Besides this can you post your json data instead of image. You can found json data in Firebase. In **Firebase Realtime Database's top right corner -> Click 3 dots menu -> Export JSON**

Comment: please,review my json data, i had posted it too

Comment: this is not working, the problem is not in the reference, i already fetch the data, in the DataSnapShot object, but i cannot parse it to my FirebaseTripDataHolder object

Comment: I have tested with your `json` and found different problem `com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.lang.Long to String`. And fixed this problem using my updated answer. check it

Comment: Really, you are so amazing, i just removed one step back from the query and it's really working like a sharm! thanks v.much dear

Comment: may you edit that model to retreive FirebaseTripDataHolder.java in order to fetch nested details in **customer coordinates, customer information, and destinationCoordinates** , thanks

Comment: And for your other nested object like **customer coordinates, customer information, and destinationCoordinates**, Please create another post to keep these thread clean. It's already bulky with lots of information. Hope you understand. Thanks